# Django view not returning what I want

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to show the multiplication table of a number from a form. Here is my tamplate.

```
<form method="post" action="/home/result/">
    <p>Enter your name</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="nombre"></p>
    <p>Enter you last name</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="apellido"></p>
    <p>Enter number for the table of that number</p>
    <p><input type="number" name="table1"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="Submit"></p>


</form>
```

Now, here is my view

```
    @csrf_exempt
def get_name(request):
    numbers = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        nombre = request.POST.get('nombre')
        apellido = request.POST.get('apellido')
        table = request.POST.get('table1')

        for i in range(1, 13):
            numbers.append(i*table)

        context = {
            'nombre': nombre,
            'apellido': apellido,
            'numbers': numbers
        }

        template = loader.get_template('home/result.html')

        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
    else:
        template = loader.get_template('home/nombre.html')
        return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

Here is my other view, result.html

```
<p>Hello {{ nombre }} {{ apellido }}</p>
    {% for number in numbers %}
        {{ number }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
```

So, I enter 6, this is what I see. I tried this on my terminal and I get the right result. What could it be wrong?

```
6
66
666
6666
66666
666666
6666666
66666666
666666666
6666666666
66666666666
666666666666
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're having here is that the '6' you are passing to the view is actually a string. So when you multiply it, you are performing string multiplication which just repeats the string.

To fix this, you must convert the number to an integer by doing `int(table)`

Comment: Note that `int(table)` could cause a `ValueError` if the user doesn't submit a number. If you use [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/) and an [`IntegerField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield), then Django will take care of validating the input and converting the value to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon the other answer given, table is a string when you get it from the post body. You must convert it to an integer with the `int()` function. In the context of your code:

```
def get_name(request):
numbers = []
if request.method == 'POST':
    nombre = request.POST.get('nombre')
    apellido = request.POST.get('apellido')
    table = request.POST.get('table1', 0) # this adds a default, in case table1 is empty 
    table = int(table) # converts the string into an integer
...
```

then you just continue on how you were from there.

for reference, you should never use `@csrf_exempt` in a production application unless you have a really, really good reason for doing so.